Cannot Find Fragment that implements Listener
I have been trying to call a callback of Fragment A from Fragment B but I can seem to find an the appropriate Fragment A when I call onAttach of Fragment B.
More specifically, Fragment A file:
class FragmentA : Fragment(), MyAdapterClickListener, FragmentB.CallBListener {
  
    override fun testFunFromFragmentB(myVarA: String) { someFun(myVarA) }

[...]

    // This is how I setup the navigation to FragmentB
    override fun MyAdapterClick(myVarB: Parcel) {
        val action = FragmentDirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(myVarB)
        Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)
    }

In Fragment B file:
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    interface CallBListener {
        fun testFunFromFragmentB(myVarA: String)
    }

    private var myListener: CallBListener? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        myListener = findListener()

        if (myListener == null) {
            throw RuntimeException("$context must implement CallBListener")
        }
    }


    private fun findListener(): CallBListener? {
        val fragmentManager = parentFragmentManager

        // Traverse the fragment stack to find the fragment that implements CallBListener
        for (fragment in fragmentManager.fragments) {
            if (fragment is CallBListener) {
                return fragment
            }
        }


        // Return null if no fragment implements CallBListener
        return null
    }

More info : The app is a single activity application, with multiple fragments.
Navigation is implemented as follows :
val action = AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment( myVar1, myVar2 ) 
Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)

Furthermore, I am using ViewBindings.
I have tried different variations of findListener, but I cannot seem to find the FragmentA.
How can I call someFun of FragmentA, from FragmentB?
--
Solution:
So, I could not make this work. I tried different approaches including :
parentFragmentManager.fragments

But due to the way that NavHostFragment works, I couldn't call a function of FragmentA from FragmentB. I am also not entirely sure, but it seems like FragmentA is not running while FragmentB is.
So, in order to solve this, I used a shared view model. It looks like this:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

 private var _myVar = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = -1 }
    val myVar: LiveData<Int> get() = _myVar


    fun incrementDoneFlag() {
        _myVar.value = (_myVar.value ?: 0) + 1
    }

I know that this solution does not solve the problem of generally finding FragmentA from FragmentB, but the principle of having a shared view model should solve every problem in that category.

You don't have to set up a listener if you want to call something in FragmentB from FragmentA. You can get an instance of FragmentA with a method like parentFragmentManager and then call the function you wanted to call. This avoids the extra complexity of setting up a listener.

 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
         
        //Find fragment by Id
        val fragmentA = 
        parentFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA_container) as? FragmentA 

        //Call the function you need
        fragmentA?.someFun()

    }



I am implementing this app as a single activity, with multiple fragments. Therefore I use :
val action =
                            AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment(
                                myVar1,
                                myVar2
                            )
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(action)

Furthermore, I am using ViewBindings.
I don't think I can use findFragmentById

Since you're using a single activity with multiple fragments and ViewBindings, the findFragmentById() method might not work if you're not adding fragments directly into a container.
Instead, you can access FragmentA by using parentFragmentManager and identifying the fragment through tags or other mechanisms (if available). Here’s how you can modify it:
val fragmentA = parentFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is FragmentA } as? FragmentA fragmentA?.someFun()

Solution:
So, I could not make this work. I tried different approaches including :
parentFragmentManager.fragments
But due to the way that NavHostFragment works, I couldn't call a function of FragmentA from FragmentB. I am also not entirely sure, but it seems like FragmentA is not running while FragmentB is.
So, in order to solve this, I used a shared view model. It looks like this:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

 private var _myVar = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = -1 }
    val myVar: LiveData<Int> get() = _myVar


    fun incrementDoneFlag() {
        _myVar.value = (_myVar.value ?: 0) + 1
    }

I know that this solution does not solve the problem of generally finding FragmentA from FragmentB, but the principle of having a shared view model should solve every problem in that category.
